Identify this Bollywood comedic action movie when a car jumps other cars whilst a police officer is sitting relaxed on the bonnet...!
I saw a video clip on Facebook recently, of a Bollywood Movie.
The clip starts with a Toyota Land Cruiser marked "police" jumping on a romp with a guy chilled on the car's bonnet with his back on the windshield, and the car is jumping over two other cars: the second one which is burning. The men in the car and the one sitting on it are all wearing brown uniforms which I presumed were police officer's uniforms.
There are some three ladies besides the first car and are looking at the "flying" car in awe. 

The car then proceeds to land and do a few donuts before the guy on the bonnet springs up, whilst one in the car throws him a gun that looks like a shotgun, and then he fires it towards a group of other cars coming his way.

I tried perusing the comments in the video but nobody seems to know what movie it is from. 
The clip can be found on Facebook on this link.
Can somebody identify this one??

This is not a Bollywood movie but a Kollywood(Tamil) movie. The movie's name is Aambala which was later dubbed to Hindi(Bollywood) and Telugu(Tollywood). The actor you see on the car is Vishal. It is apparently an action comedy movie, hence the extravagant and unreal entry of the male lead.
